# Jquery animation triggered between scroll positions

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I want to use Jquery's .animate to fade an element in between two points and fade it out when the scroll position is not between them.  Here's my code, which doesn't work:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
 var top = $(this).scrollTop();
 if(top > 50 && top < 200 ){
     $('#videosection').animate({opacity:'1'}); 
 }
 if(top < 50 && top > 200 ){
     $('#videosection').animate({opacity:'1'}); 
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> if(top < 50 && top > 200 ){

This code will never work. It's impossible to be less than 50 and more than 200 at the same time - there are no such numbers in this universe :) . That's why Doa's code does not work.

Try this code:

```
var isCurrentlyVisible = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(!isCurrentlyVisible && top > 50 && top < 200 ){
        isCurrentlyVisible = true;
        $('#videosection').stop().animate({
            "opacity":"1"
        });
    }
    if(isCurrentlyVisible && (top < 50 || top > 200 )){
        isCurrentlyVisible = false;
        $('#videosection').stop().animate({
            "opacity":"0"
        });
    }
}).trigger('scroll');
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8mTb6/) on jsFiddle.net

Comment: Is there a way to re-use the script for an entire class of elements and set the in and out points in the HTML?

Comment: Yes, of course there is a way. I can say more: there are lots of ways to do this - it depends on situation and your needs. You can handle scroll for each element separately or you can handle scroll in one place and change visibility of each element depending on scrolling offset.